# Circular segment using CSS/CSS3

Tags: css

Is there any variant to draw a [circular segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment) using just CSS/CSS3?

[image: Circle with a dashed line across the top. The section within the line, the segment, is shaded green and is less than half of the cirle. Radius, segment height, etc. are also labeled.]

I need that green part of circle.

I was trying this:

```css
div {
  width: 86px;
  height: 22px;
  background-color: green;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 42px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 42px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

But it doesn't look like a circular segment.

Comment: Can you provide an image or something showing what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @OllyHodgson [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment) - check this article on Wikipedia. I need that green part of circle. It should have approx. width:86px, and height:22px (and it's like 1/2 of full radius (not diameter) of circle).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The width and height of the div should be same to produce a circle.

eg: http://jsfiddle.net/wGzMd/

Here is the css:

```
div{
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
left: 50px;
width:100px;
height:100px;
border: 1px solid green;
background: green;
border-radius: 360px;
} ​
```

---

**EDIT (for segment):**

http://jsfiddle.net/wGzMd/3/

CSS:

```
div.outerClass{
 position: absolute;
 left: 50px;
 top: 50px;
 height: 25px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

div.innerClass{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 border: 1px solid green;
 border-radius: 360px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="outerClass"><div class="innerClass"></div></div>
```

Comment: thanks, but I need not full circle, but just segment. You can check this article [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment) , to clearly understand what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Maryna, plz check the new code for segment with fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wGzMd/3/

Comment: you are genius! It's exactly what I need! I suggest you to write to css-tricks, to add this shape to site!

Comment: The border radius doesn't have to be `360px` here, it has nothing to do with degrees. It just has to be half the height of the element, in this case, `50px`.

Answer (score 4):

Hey check to this site http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

and this http://www.russellheimlich.com/blog/pure-css-shapes-triangles-delicious-logo-and-hearts/

and this

http://www.css3shapes.com/

**Css**

```
#oval {
width: 86px;
height: 22px;
background: green;
-moz-border-radius: 50px / 25px;
border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0 / 47px;
-webkit-border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0 / 47px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="oval"></div>
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/carTT/

and create any shape in pure css  as like you .................

Comment: thanks, I checked css-tricks article before, but didn't find what I'm looking for.

Comment: that's much closer to what I want. If only this can be a little bit smoother. Can you explain me what does "/ 47px" mean?

Comment: ok, I found answer on http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-radius/ and that's probably, what I need. Just to play around with this values. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Half circle: 
http://www.paulund.co.uk/how-to-create-different-shapes-in-css

```
 div {
 height:45px;
 width:90px;
 border-radius: 0 0 90px 90px;
 -moz-border-radius: 0 0 90px 90px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 90px 90px;
 background:green;}
```

Comment: @Peteris , half of circle is easy, but I need less than half:) I updated my question with link to Wikipedia, to clarify my question